# CarouselView not showing on Android if in a modal page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to handle a login/registration form inside a CarouselView (https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView). In my MainPage, I have this:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // Is user logged in?
    if (!(bool)Application.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"]) // He is not logged in
    {
        await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginRegistrationPage());
    }
}
```

LoginRegistrationPage contains a CarouselView and its first page is the registration form, while the second page is the login form.
iOS is fine, but on Android I get a blank page. The CarouselView is visible everywhere except that in a modal page. (I have tried to set LoginRegistrationPage as MainPage and to put it inside a simple Navigation rather than a modal one, both work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of CarouselView.
This solved: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/pull/329